# Command build with relative path Sublime Text2

Tags: c++, build, mingw, sublimetext2

I've installed Sublime Text2 Portable, and I've installed MinGW portable on my pendrive. I changed cmd on c++.sublime-build to put locate relative path to g++.exe, but I get a error: Not Found.

How can indicate the relative path to compilation command?

Comment: Is [this the same question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815493/sublime-text-build-system-that-just-make/13827685#13827685)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

- indicate a path relative to **Package Folder** *${packages}*;
  variable.
- Or you can use the '***path***' option.

Example:

```json
...    
"cmd": ["${packages}/../../../../../usr/bin/g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
"path": "~/.:/usr/local/bin",
...
```

Others variables can be found [here](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html).

Comment: Works fine!.. but now I have this error: [Decode error - output not utf-8]

Comment: Maybe you need to [change the encoding](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1535).

Comment: Now I get this: as.exe not found how set path to sublime found these  executables?

Comment: You can use the 'path' option.

Comment: See this [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815493/sublime-text-build-system-that-just-make/13827685#13827685) for another discussion of PATH issues.