# Sublime Text Build System that just "make"

Tags: makefile, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I'm trying to build my project by simple executing `make` in the top directory. However, when I do, I get the following error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
[cmd:  [u'make']]
[dir:  /Users/jonathanong/Workspace/template]
[path: /usr/local/bin]
[Finished]
```

This is after setting the build configuration to `Make`.

I'm on Sublime Text 2.0.1, OS X 10.8.2. My Makefile consists of executing globally installed `node.js` binaries. What do I have to do?

Comment: Just in case Linux users were searching this: [Ctrl+M to run Makefile with Sublime+Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21709896/562769)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is because `make` is not in your PATH.  If you can build in the terminal, use `which make` to figure out the path to `make`, and then add that to the path for build.  You can edit the [makefile build system](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) to add your path.

Your new makefile rule should look like:

```js
{
   "cmd": ["make"],
   "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
   "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder:${file_path}}}",
   "selector": "source.makefile",
   "path": "/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin",
   "variants":
    [
      {
        "name": "Clean",
        "cmd": ["make", "clean"]
      },
      {
        "name": "Test",
        "cmd": ["make", "test"]
      }
    ]
}
```

This is basically the default `make` target, but I added to the PATH, and (of course) a test target.  You may have to extend the PATH to find gcc, ifort, or whatever you are using to compile.  [Use `:` to separate directories on Linux and Mac, and `;` on Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29). You can also change other environment variables, I had to set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and CPATH so that my libraries and include directories would be available.

It should be saved as Make (OSX).sublime-build in the User directory of your Sublime preferences.  The (OSX) will ensure that this file is only used on Mac, so when you copy your preferences to a non-mac computer, you won't gunk up the path.

Comment: does that mean i would have to make a build file for every single project?

Comment: You can have both user setting build files and project level build files.

Comment: alright so my path is `/usr/bin/make`, so I made `/usr/bin` my path. Now I'm getting `make: component: No such file or directory`. I guess I need to let sublime text know about `/usr/local/bin/component` and/or `/usr/local/bin`. How do I do that?

Comment: well `/user/bin:/user/local/bin` works. not sure why `:` is a separator. thanks!

Comment: `:` is the separator for `PATH` and `PATH`-like environment variables (on Linux and Mac - Windows uses ;).

Comment: I take it this means that Sublime Text 2 isn't looking at the $PATH environment variable when it runs Build? make is also in /usr/bin on my system.

Comment: @dpk a better question is probably "what does $PATH look like when sublime is launched?"  If you're launching it from the window manager, I don't think that PATH will have the local modifications that you have made in your .bashrc, for instance.

Comment: @dbw In my case I have a program in /usr/bin that sublime could not find. I was making the assumption that $PATH included /usr/bin at the time sublime was launched, but I guess it might not have. That'd be exceedingly strange, though, eh?

Comment: I don't know if that's strange.  I'd check on the defaults for your distribution.

Comment: Just type `import os; os.environ['PATH']` in the ST console and you use which PATH is used...

Answer (score 1):

A much preferable solution is IMO to adjust the PATH in a plugin, so you have to set it just once for all build systems and all plugins calling external commands.

You can just do

```
import os
os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + '/my/extra/path'
```

Real world example lives at https://github.com/schlamar/ST3User/blob/master/preferences.py

Answer (score 0):

If your makefile works by going to the directory its in and typing `make`, then [this](http://www.l3oc.com/2015/05/sublime-text-editor-easy-build-system.html) custom sublime-build file works:

```
 {  
      "working_dir": "${file_path}",  
      "cmd": ["make"],  
      "variants":  
 [  
   {  
        "working_dir": "${file_path}",  
     "name": "Run",  
     "cmd": ["./a.out"]  
   }  
 ]  
 }
```