# Ctrl+M to run Makefile with Sublime+Linux

Tags: makefile, sublimetext2

I'm currently thinking about switching from Pluma (former gEdit) to Sublime Text. What I have seen so far from Sublime Text is pretty nice.

I currently test Submlime Text 2 and would like it to execute `make` in the folder of the document that is currently opened when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>.

Is that possible? How do I do it?

When I currently hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> it does build the LaTeX document I currently view, but it does not use my `Makefile`. That is bad, because it fails to build my main document which has a more complicated build process.

After setting `Tools > Build System > Make` it runs make, but not the Makefile of the current documents folder.

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13827685/562769), but it seems to focus on OS X.

Comment: That answer you linked to is the answer you need. You will need to change the path accordingly. The answer says to save it as `Make (OSX).sublime-build`, you can cut (OSX) out or just put (WIN) instead.

Comment: @RyanB: I've tried it again and it worked now. The problems were a missing `,` in the code provided in the other question and `PATH` issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13827685/562769) was almost what I needed:

Do the following steps to make Sublime Text 2 (ST2) execute `make` when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd> under Linux (in my case: Linux Mint, a Debian based distribution):

1. Get the path of `make` with `which make`
2. Go to your ST2 user config directory
   `/home/[Your user name]/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User`
3. Insert a file called `Make (Linux).sublime-build` with the content from below.
4. Choose `Tools > Build System > Make (Linux)` in ST2

You might notice that ST2 has a different PATH than you have in your shell. See [Sublime Text 2: custom PATH and PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8574919/562769).

## Make (Linux).sublime-build

You might have to adjust `path` to your needs. I've simply put the content of `echo $PATH` in this field (which is much more than the simple example from below).

```
{
   "cmd": ["make"],
   "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
   "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder:${file_path}}}",
   "selector": "source.makefile",
   "path": "/usr/bin/:/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux",

    "variants":
    [
      {
        "name": "Clean",
        "cmd": ["make", "clean"]
      },
      {
        "name": "Test",
        "cmd": ["make", "test"]
      }
    ]
}
```